# Expression for nesting count of elements using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, nested, depth

in an xml schema nesting of <item>s is allowed unbounded e.g. in an unordered list of items (which is <randlist> for random list). These items may contain subitems that may be sublisted using <item> as a subelement within another list element such as <randlist> or <seqlist> for ordered lists.

Now I want to detect a nesting of more then 3 nesting depth levels in a document to apply some constraints on it. Using xpath this is what should be allowed unconditioned:

randlist//item

or

randlist//item//item

or

randlist//item//item//item

but

randlists with more then 3 item nesting depth levels should be prohibited, e.g.

randlist//item//item//item//item

How I can use xpath to formulate an expression that expresses a nesting of  elements beyond the third level?

thank in advance

sorry people! so here the example goes

```
<randlist> <!-- first level (not nested at all): allowed -->
    <item>
        This is the first item of an unordered enumeration of items that are prosa altogether.
    </item>
    <item>
        <randlist> <!-- second level (nested): allowed -->
            <item>
                This is the first item of an unordered enumeration of items that are prosa altogether.
            </item>
            <item>
                Another item with some information in the nested unordered list.
            </item>
            <item>
                <seqlist> <!-- third level (double nested): allowed -->
                    <item>
                        This is the first item of an ordered enumeration of items (it may be shown with the number 1).
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        This is the second item of an ordered enumeration of items (it may be shown with the number 2).
                        <randlist> <!-- fourth level (triple nested): should be prohibited -->
                            <item>
                                This is the first item of an unordered enumeration of items.
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                This is the second item of an unordered enumeration of items.
                            </item>
                        </randlist>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        This is the third item of an ordered enumeration of items (it may be shown with the number 3).
                    </item>
                </seqlist>
            </item>
        </randlist>
    </item>
</randlist>
```

I need to detect more then 3 levels of item lists, i.e. the fourth level and more. I need something like e.g. randlist[count(nesting(item))>3], if there were a function like "nesting" in xpath.

Comment: can you show XML example and add what you want to get?

Comment: Agreed, can you give us some sample XML?

Comment: You have the example as "Answer" but of course it is not answered at all :)

Comment: I am writing an answer to your question. Could you please remove your answer and edit the question to include the sample XML?

Comment: example moved to the original question as requested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the expression that you provided yourself:

```
randlist//item//item//item//item
```

This will select any item that has three or more item ancestors.

More efficient might be

```
randlist//item[count(ancestor::item) > 2]
```

but that depends on the XPath processor you are using.

Comment: oh this seems to be the expression I was looking for item[count(ancestor::item) > 2] . thanks I will try it out

Comment: and when I think further: you are right! the expression with the four items will also detect nestings with five or more item elements. I am relatively new to xpath so I sometimes need my time :)

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is a little tricky to know **exactly** what your desired output is, but I think that one of the following suggestions should be sufficient, or help you reach your goal.

As a general example, you can count the number of elements past a certain level of nesting by passing a set of nodes/elements to the `count` XPath function. For example:

**XML**

```
<randlist>
    <item>
        <content>Example Content</content>
        <subitem>
          <p>Content</p>
          <p2>More Content</p2>
        </subitem>
    </item>
</randlist>
```

**XPath**

```
count(randlist/item//*)
```

This will count the number of elements that are descendants of item elements that are direct children of randlist elements. The double-slash `//` means that the XPath searches for descendants, and the `*` operator is a wildcard which matches any elements, regardless of element name. It will therefore return **4** - beacuse there are 4 elements: `content`, `subitem`, `p` and `p2`.

In your case, I think you are looking to detect `randlist` and `seqlist` elements that are located within three levels of nesting of `item`. If you want to detect this occurrence, you could use:

```
count(randlist//item//item//item//randlist|randlist//item//item//item//seqlist)
```

The `|` operator computes the union of the two sets. If you want to detect the occurrence of **any** element located within three levels of nesting of `item`, again, you should use the wildcard operator `*`:

```
count(randlist//item//item//item//*)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! the problem is that I want to detect more than 3 levels of nesting. so it is not a fix number. I think I will test something like

randlist//item[count(ancestor::item) > 3]

as suggested below as soon as I am in the office and work with XmlSpy again :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `randlist` is always the root element of the XML document, this is one possible XPath expression to check if it contains more than 3 level nested `item` elements :

```
randlist[.//item[count(ancestor::item)>=3]]
```

Comment: okay a similar answer Michael Kay posted also. thank you all for your good ideas